# Is there a way to draw in my vs code editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor, draw

Is there any way to draw (using the mouse as a pen) in a (say) python file, and have the image part get commented out? I feel sometimes it's nice to visually explain what the next bit of code is doing.

I would like to know if there's any extension, etc that makes it possible in a vs code editor, but answers for other editors are also welcome.

Also, on how such a file could be saved and rendered.

Comment: I tried googling "`vscode whiteboard extension`" and found this: [`lostintangent.vsls-whiteboard`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lostintangent.vsls-whiteboard). Doesn't allow drawing on top of other editor tabs, but better than nothing I guess?